# On what basis Pushpadanta states that chanting his Shiva Mahimna Stotram is greater than Spiritual initiation, austerities, etc?

Tags: shiva, stotra, shiva-mahimna-stotra

Verse 36 states: 
Shiv Mahimna Stotram - Text 36

> Diksha danam tapas tirtham jnanamyaga-dikah kriyah,
>
> mahimnah stava pathasya kallam narhanti shodashim
>
> Initiation into spiritual life, charities, austerities, pilgrimages,
>   practice of yoga, performance of sacrificial rites – none of these
>   give even a sixteenth part of the merit that one gets by reciting the
>   hymn on the greatness of Shiva. (36)

Pushpadanta wrote the Shiva Mahimna Stotram to seek forgiveness from Lord Shiva.

Did he just state this out of flattery for Lord Shiva?

Comment: This kind of questions can not be answered. Stotras praise themselves like that often. This is done to instill faith in the reciters mind. If we go on asking "On what basis.." then there are no answers. More so if the Stotra itself does not shed any light as to why it has stated such a Phalasruti.

Comment: So does that mean all that mentioned isn’t true?

Comment: No we can not say that it isn't true. But we can not give any reasons either as to why such a thing is said.

Comment: Shiva mahimna stotram is a type of hymnal composition by Gandharva shreshta Pushpadantha which extensively installs Parameshvara Shiva's glory in the hearts of his devotees. This hymn consists of everything that can be offered to Lord, so there are many sayings that who can't chant Sri Rudram as it's little tough, one can chant or mediate upon this Shiva mahimna stotram which washes of all sins and takes you towards the supreme.